# Get all the includes from an Entity Framework Query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, include, group-by

I've the following Entity Model : Employee has a Company and a Company has Employees.

When using the **Include** statement like below:

```
var query = context.Employees.Include(e => e.Company);
query.Dump();
```

All related data is retrieved from the database correctly. (Using LEFT OUTER JOIN on Company table)

The problem is hat when I use the GroupBy() from System.Linq.Dynamic to group by Company.Name, the Employees are missing the Company data because the **Include** is lost.
Example:

```
var groupByQuery = query.GroupBy("new (Company.Name as CompanyName)", "it");
groupByQuery.Dump();
```

Is there a way to easily retrieve the applied Includes on the 'query' as a string collection, so that I can include them in the dynamic GroupBy like this:

```
var groupByQuery2 = query.GroupBy("new (Company, Company.Name as CompanyName)", "it");
groupByQuery2.Dump();
```

I thought about using the ToString() functionality to get the SQL Command like this:

```
string sql = query.ToString();
```

And then use RegEx to extract all LEFT OUTER JOINS, but probably there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

if you're creating the query in the first place - I'd always opt to save the includes (and add to them if you're making a composite query/filtering).

e.g. instead of returning just 'query' return `new QueryContext {Query = query, Includes = ...}`

I'd like to see a more elegant solution - but I think that's your best bet.

Otherwise you're looking at expression trees, visitors and all those nice things.
SQL parsing isn't that straight either - as queries are not always that simple (often a combo of things etc.).

e.g. there is a `span' inside the query object (if you traverse a bit) which seems to be holding the 'Includes' but it's not much help.